# Integrate Wordpress and bbpress profiles?

Tags: profiles, bbpress, customization

I have installed bbforum plugin in my wordpress. However It has two separate profiles for the blog  users and the forum users. Blog users have profiles url:

/author/test/

While forum users have profile:

/forums/users/test/

Is it possible to integrate both profiles and make only a single profile? So that the users in forums also have same url as the blog profile? Thanks

Comment: which version of bbPress?

Comment: Interesting question, but note that an author does not means it should be also a forum member and vice-versa, I think this avoid confusion. Also related to this, BuddyPress and bbPress profiles will be merged in the next version (https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4357)

Comment: What about redirecting all requests for `/author/test/` to `/forums/users/test`, or visa-versa? Or do they each have unique data that you want to merge into a single page?

Answer (score 1):

Get [redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) plugin to redirect the /profile.php to bbpress profile. Then there is a plugin called [admin menu editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) where you can completely remove the profile  the admin menu (and other unwanted admin menu items).

Or you can replace the wordpress profile with just email and password 
[wordpress.org/extend/plugins/change-password-e-mail/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/change-password-e-mail/)

Answer (score -1):

Personally, i'd go for another plugin: WP Symposium (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-symposium/). It allows a lot of customization, provides profile and forum functionality (among many others) and the plugin author is very good at listening to its users.

Answer (score -3):

The short answer is that it is possible. The long answer is that you'll likely have to adjust one or the other's authentication methods to use the other scripts functions. You would also need to alter the session handling sections of both codes so that a user will be logged into both when they log into one of the scripts. This can be extremely complicated and will require a break check every time either application is altered.

A possible third option is to add a hook into the user creation methods of both scripts and add the user to the alternate application at the same time. You would also need to update the password for the alternate application at the same time as well. The big problem with this method is that users would still need to log into both applications independently.

Comment: Haven't downvoted but agree with them. Let's see, the first two options are the same: hack WP or BBF core code? The "third" doesn't solve the problem?